# xfce4 on Ubuntu Server 19.04. Update or bad install?

Tags: server, software-installation, launcher, xfce, desktop-environments

I just installed Ubuntu server and XFCE4, however the desktop is completely different than any other xfce I have installed, with a gnome-like launcher and both Ubuntu and Debian screen backgrounds, as well as no start menu or panel. But Thunar is there.

I understand that there were a lot of changes to Xubuntu 19.04, but nothing I read about said anything about this. So take a look at my screenshot of a fresh install of Ubuntu Server + xfce4 (and a few utilities).

[image: Note the launcher, the presence of thunar, and the two wallpapers (they are on different GPUs)]

Is this expected (nevermind the checkerboard pattern thing, sometimes my graphics card does that).

Additional notes: This happened on two installs back-to-back. Also, the mouse tracking and stuff are really slow, although that could be due to having five monitors spread across three video cards, but I don't remember this being an issue in the past)

Comment: No, I want to use Ubuntu Server (this machine is a host for desktop virtualization with KVM), I just want a very minimal XFCE desktop environment for ease of administration. I have done this just fine in the past. I installed it by installing Ubuntu Server 19.04 via the classic installer and then running `sudo apt-get update` `sudo apt-get upgrade` and then `sudo apt install xfce4 xfce4-screenshooter geany firefox gparted`. 
Those were literally the only commands I ran on the system. Also I did a run with memtest recently and got no errors.

Comment: You didn't install the xubuntu desktop, instead xfce4 (https://packages.ubuntu.com/disco/xfce4) which does include desktop-base (*common files for the Debian Desktop* (https://packages.ubuntu.com/disco/desktop-base) which suggests `gnome` (*Full GNOME Desktop Environment, with extra components*) so I'd check your logs and see what you actually installed; you may have accepted the suggest packages (https://packages.ubuntu.com/disco/gnome) pulling in gnome because of your provided command.  If you did hit 'y' or -y to accept recommends, you should consider --no-install-recommends

Comment: I am sure that I have always installed xfce4, not desktop in the past and it was always fine. I did run with `-y` but I never manually turned those down in the past. Something changed.

Comment: Packages are built for each release, the move of XFCE to GTK+3 is almost complete, so XFCE has been changing heaps of late, so the 'something's changed' comment bewilders me.  The GTK+3 move (from old GTK+2) should be compete by 19.10; but do you *not* read release notes? Maybe LXDE (being it's ~dead) would be a better choice as it doesn't move much (Lubuntu switched to LXQt a couple of release back) if you don't like change.

Comment: @guiverc I'm not the best about reading release notes, but I don't see anything there about moving to the GNOME launcher. And did they stop doing branding? What's with the Debian wallpaper?

Comment: You didn't use Xubuntu intended packages, you used upstream's xfce4 which pulled in desktop-base or "*common files for the Debian Desktop*" without the Xubuntu team's changes. Xubuntu branding is there in Xubuntu, and no Xubuntu doesn't use GNOME launcher.  XFCE though is going thru big changes, XFCE 4.14 is in RC currently!  (all GTK+3)

Comment: I see. Well, in the past xfce4 always installed with the Xubuntu mouse logo as the default background. I guess as per your answer the dependencies and defaults changed such that installing plain xfce4 using -y results in thunar + GNOME launcher.

Comment: You may find if you logout of the gui, clicking on the gear logo  will let you select XFCE as default instead of what does looks like gnome-shell (gnome 3). The upstream changes (ie. debian) are mostly done by the same people that produce Xubuntu anyway.   (https://wiki.bluesabre.org/disco_changes).  A side note, your issue could be caused by https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libnotify/0.7.7-4ubuntu2 which didn't impact Xubuntu, but did impact Lubuntu (https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lubuntu-meta/+bug/1815837) but your install method may have triggered it due to libnotify change

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You didn't install the xubuntu desktop, instead xfce4

https://packages.ubuntu.com/disco/xfce4

which does include `desktop-base`  https://packages.ubuntu.com/disco/desktop-base described as

> *common files for the Debian Desktop*

which suggests `gnome` https://packages.ubuntu.com/disco/gnome

> Full GNOME Desktop Environment, with extra components

so I'd check your logs and see what you actually installed.

You may have accepted the suggested/recommended packages pulling in `gnome` because of your provided command, esp. if you 'y' or included a `-y` to accept recommends; possibly you should consider `--no-install-recommends`

Comment: This behavior must be new, because that is what I have always done in the past and not ended up with Gnome.